# Changing site URL in wordpress doesn't work

Tags: html, website, css, wordpress, hosting

I'm trying to change the address of my website from .ca/wp to just .ca, so in general settings of my dashboard I changed it, but it still shows as my "under construction" page. Changing it also doesn't let me access my WordPress dashboard, but going to the old .ca/wp directs to an unstylized version of my site. Any help?

Comment: I had this same problem a couple years back but I do not rememerb what the fix was but I think it was an option with URL name maybe. you should see setting close to that or name like it or with it in it

Answer (score 0):

I've seen quite a few different issues moving WordPress.. What I've discovered is the step by step long way always works! (Access to FTP and Database (I like phpMyAdmin) is often needed)

1. First back up everything! - export xml (under tools) backup database and copy all files (especially the wp-content directory)
2. Follow the codex instructions here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress - most likely the section titled: Moving Directories on your existing server.
3. Depending on how it goes your images may not display, if this is the case or any other linked files or media aren't showing search for plugins to update media links after moving WordPress or change the file paths manually.

Best of luck!